# Перебор таблицы и динамическое создание к-во переменных

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть таблица выводящаяся аяксом

```
<tr>
    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" value="7" class="id"></td>
    <td>765675</td>
    <td>site.ru</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" value="160" class="taxes">
    </td><td><input type="checkbox" id="selection" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" value="5" class="id"></td>
    <td>09808</td>
    <td>site2.ru</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" value="140" class="taxes">
    </td><td><input type="checkbox" id="selection" checked="checked"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" value="20" class="id"></td>
    <td>46546758</td>
    <td>site3.ru</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" value="" class="taxes">
    </td><td><input type="checkbox" id="selection"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" value="24" class="id"></td>
    <td>675876</td>
    <td>site4.ru</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="8" value="" class="taxes">
    </td><td><input type="checkbox" id="selection"></td>
</tr>
```

Мне нужно перебрать ее и взять 2 значения с инпута и вторую ячейку загнать их в переменные и переслать на сервак делаю перебор так:

```
$("#test tr").each(function(){ 
    if($(this).find("input:checked")){
        console.log(this);
    } 
});
```

Выбирает строки те что мне нужны, но когда пользователь выбирает 3 или 4 строки в примера то есть там где нет чекеда после аякса то выборка не видит их. И второй вопрос вдогонку: как после переборки загнать 3 значения с каждой строки в отдельную переменную, чтобы потом на серваке корректно их отработать (строк может быть переменное количество, не выйдет напрямую указать что есть 3 переменных 3 строки в которые они загоняются, т.е. переменные нужно как то создавать в зависимости от количества выбранных строк).

Comment: дак и отправьте на сервер массив, в чем проблема то?

Comment: @teran ты имеешь в виду всю таблицу без перебора или все строки после перебора которые селектор выбрал?

Comment: после фильтрации, конечно.

Comment: @teran хз можно попробовать просто хотелось все отфильтровать до сервака, а на сервак аяксом отправить готовые уже переменные с данными.

Comment: дак про это и речь. Я про то, что неизвестное число переменных на сервер можно отправить в виде массива.

Comment: ну или так но все равно надо селектор нормальный сделать и массиву ключи надо тогда давать т.к. 3 переменные связанные между собой (ну это я думаю просто фором увеличивать счетчик и все).

Comment: что касается, почему не все строки попадают в лог, то проверяйте в `if` не просто `find()` а `find().length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос об отправке на сервер различного числа переменных решается путем отправки на сервер массива.

Если вы сами строите html-таблицу приведенную выше, то и ячейке из которой берете данные лучше добавить какой-то класс, или атрибут (чтобы не зависеть от структуры таблицы/или вообще не таблицы) и заодно проверить корректность испоьзования идентификаторов. Так, к примеру,  у вас все инпуты имеют `id="selected"`, что в целом не корректно.

```
$("#test").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  //массив, который будем передавать
  var data = [];

  $("tr").each(function(idx, row){
    // проверка, что коллекация найденных строк не пуста
    if($(row).find("input:checked").length){

      //строка отмечена, добавить данные в массив
      data.push({
          cellValue : parseInt($(row).find("td").eq(1).text()),
          taxes : $(row).find(".taxes").val()
      });
    }
  });


  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  // отправить данные  
  $.post('/script.php', data, function(data){
      // ...
  });
});
```